# How do I prevent someone from sharing a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I have a user who has access to library A and library A is restricted to security group A can I make an assumption that this user can not share this document to someone in security group B by clicking on the Share icon from the Files tab within the Ribbon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library A is Shared with only Group A.
Then user of Group B can not access anything from Library A.